# Writing a method to skip whitespace in an input file - Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, computer-science

I am writing a program and am creating a method called `skipWhiteSpace()` which will call `GetNextChar()` which reads and returns each individual character in the file. The method must skip spaces, tabs, newlines, and ALSO recognize and skip over all comments, whether they start with `{` or `(*` until the end of the comment with the matching `}` or `*)`.

```
private char skipWhiteSpace() {
       // TODO
    }
```

I would appreciate some help writing this `skipWhiteSpace()` method.

Comment: Considering that `inputFile` is probably some type of reader (probably a `Scanner` object, you didn't provide that information), calling `next()` will retrieve the next token, meaning the next `String` that is read. Your method `getNextChar()` (please try to use Java naming conventions) will only return the **first** character of the read `String`. The rest is omitted. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sorry, the regex you want is /(\S+)/g

Answer (score 1):

`hasNext()` and `next()` sounds like `inputFile` is an instance of Scanner.

Scanner doesn't read a file character for character.

Scanner already omits whitespace. It doesn't function as 'read char by char' whatsoever. It reads all input, looking for 'the delimiter'. It throws delimiters out, and gives you everything this is in between them. Out of the box, 'the delimiter' is defined as '1 or more whitespace characters', so effectively you're already throwing all the whitespace out, but you can't ask a scanner to give you char-by-char data (it gives you tokens, one at a time, 'a token' being defined as: "all characters that occur in between 2 delimiters, where start-of-file and end-of-file also count as a delimiter".

Comment: You can set up the `Scanner` to read char-by-char data with `.useDelimiter("")` in combination with `next()` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Would it be better to use something like BufferReader for getting my inputFile? Or does that do the same as Scanner?

Comment: @User12345 yup, BufferedReader is perfect for the job of reading some text data char-by-char. Then you can just make a custom 'read()' method that invokes read(), and returns that if it is not whitespace. If it is whitespace, it repeats the process until it isn't. Voila.

Comment: @maloomeister That is a good point. Then again, you _can_ butter some toast using a hammer. Just because you can do a thing doesn't mean that it is a good idea :P

Comment: @rzwitserloot valid point :) I will keep the comment there as it is not technically incorrect (even if not actually reasonable as you said).

Comment: You return 1 character for every time you call `nextLine()`. Thus, what you pasted now does not work and cannot work. You need to test your stuff first (it's much faster than waiting for my reply, no doubt!), and switch to `read()`.